# Open modal dialog on page/component load

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

What is the best or recommended method to cause a Vuetify modal dialog to appear as soon as the page loads? Having a hard time finding examples of programmatically causing a Vuetify dialog to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to set a variable associated with v-dialog's v-model prop to 'true'.

Dialog visibility is controlled by `v-dialog`'s `v-model` property.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs